# How to select departments with no female employees

Tags: sql

The schema is as follows:

> **Employee:**   Fname, Lname, **Ssn**, Sex, *Dno*
>   **Department**:   Dname, **Dnumber**, *Mgr_ssn*

Dnumber is the primary key of department, Ssn is the primary key of employee.
Dno is a foreign key referencing Dnumber.

I tried approaching the problem with this query:

```
SELECT Dnumber, count(ssn) from DEPARTMENT    
INNER JOIN Employee   
ON Dno = Dnumber  
WHERE sex = ALL('M')
GROUP BY Dnumber
```

I thought the use of ALL would select only departments with all male employees, where the count would then be applied, however it is selecting all departments with male employees and then counting them. 
I'm on the right tracks, and seems like I'm overlooking something trivial, but have tried looking up similar questions but have found no information.

Any pointers toward similar questions or advice on where i'm misstepping would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `HAVING` (assuming that `e.sex` is defined as `NOT NULL`):

```
SELECT d.dnumber, d.dname
FROM department d
JOIN employee e
  ON e.dno = d.dnumber
GROUP BY d.dnumber, d.name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN e.sex = 'F' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

This just screams "not exists":

```
select d.*
from department d
where not exists (select 1 from employee where d.dnumber = e.dno and d.sex = 'F');
```

Incidentally, assuming that all non-females are male would not work in many databases.

Your have multiple missteps in your query.  First, `ALL()` applies to the list of values in the subquery.  It doesn't have anything to do with the outer query.  Second, it is filtering out all the females in the `WHERE`.  That is fine if you want to count the numbers, but it give you nothing to determine if there are any females.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around why the ALL doesnt work in this scenario. When you say it is applied to the values in the subquery, could you clarify? At the moment I'm seeing the operation of the query as follows - The inner join is applied on the condition of dno = dnumber and sex = ALL('M'), I'm not sure how this isn't working, as shouldnt it be going through the "sex" field for all employees of a given department and returning false as soon as it sees a female employee, meaning it wont include that department in the join? Appreciate the reply regardless! Ill need to look into !exists too

Comment: To clarify, I thought the use of ALL would not only filter out all females, but also any departments that dont satisfy this ALL. Instead the ALL seems to do nothing, and is acting as if I have sex = 'M'

Comment: @Danny . . . As a note, this should have better performance than a method that uses `join` and `group by`.